# VB 2010 Assembly doesn't load at startup

Tags: vb.net, dll

I'm a long-time Delphi programmer that's been handed an older VB app to make compatible with Win7.  (I haven't touched any species of basic since the DOS days, so I'm new to VB/VS 2010 - I've taken the beginner DevU trainings, and have a handle on the basics of VB syntax compared to Delphi, but don't have much clue on the vagaries of how VS and .NET put that code together into an app.)  The code has worked fine for years under WinXP, but it does some things (registry writes, cfg files stored in the EXE folder, etc.) that Win7 balks at.

The app references a set of assemblies that provide services to control certain industrial equipment.  The DLLs for these are in Windows\System32 so they should be found; I tried running regsvr32 on them to see if they needed to be registered, but they're missing the server entry points.  The objects for these are instantiated in the InitializeComponent() sub of frmMain.Designer.vb:

```
Me.AxDiamondctrl1 = New AxDIAMONDCTRLLib.AxDiamondctrl()
Me.AxDiamondsetupctrl1 = New AxDIAMONDSETUPCTRLLib.AxDiamondsetupctrl()
```

then, in the Me.Startup handler in ApplicationEvents.vb, a couple of the assembly methods get called to initialize things:

```
frmMain.AxDiamondctrl1.InitLowerLayer()
frmMain.AxDiamondsetupctrl1.InitCore()
```

Problem: The instantiation calls are in the InitializeComponent() handler along with all the calls to instantiate the numerous visual components on the main form.  However, at startup, the main form comes up blank, with none of the visual components (menu, toolbar, buttons, etc.)  I'm unable to trace this in the debugger, and unable to view the form in the form designer for some unknown reason, but it appears that the InitializeComponent() handler either doesn't get called or exceptions out, and since the code works under WinXP, I'm assuming it's the latter.  And because the control instances in the form object are nil, the references in the Startup handler toss exceptions.

Why would these not be loading properly?

Thanks!
Steve

Comment: The most typical scenario is that this bombs at design-time when you open the form.  Which requires these ActiveX components to be installed and functional.  And clicked on the what-the-heck-does-that-mean message box when they are not.  After which it will leave you in peace, but with a considerably trimmed InitializeComponent() method..  Peace is good.

Comment: Makes sense based on what I see - on all the other forms, dbl-clicking on the form's main entry in the solution explorer opens the form editor, but dbl-clicking on the main form's entry just opens the code editor, without giving any error message on why. (Delphi does something very similar, but gives an informative msg on which component is causing the form editor to fail.)

The question then is, how to register the AX DLLs.  Regsvr32 says there's no entry point in either of them. ???

Comment: Run the vendor-provided installer of these components.  Do *not* try to register the Ax wrappers, they are merely .net glue.

Comment: Hmmm... the AX DLLs are made by us, and installed by the installer for the main program I'm working on.  I don't currently have the source for those.  The installer has been run on my dev machine so I would expect the AXs to be registered already. Is it possible that there's a 32-vs-64-bit issue here? The app has always been used on 32-bit platforms before, and my machine is 64-bit.

Comment: You don't "make" them, they are auto-generated from the type library of the component.  Usually by the IDE when you add the reference, AxImp.exe is the tool to do it manually.  Merely glue, it is the vendor's unmanaged component that gets the actual work done.  And sure, if the project is old then it might have been built to target AnyCPU.  Which works by accident on a 32-bit OS, on a 64-bit OS you must get the main EXE project to target x86.  Right-click it > Properties > Build tab.

Comment: Project is definitely built for AnyCPU, but that's the only "Platform" option VS2010 gives me on either the Compile or Debug tab.  Is there a VS2010 setting to enable other platforms?

Comment: OK, found it under advanced compiler options.  Rebuilding with that set to x86 allows the form to load in the designer properly, but it's still coming up blank when run.  I'm trying to run down the source for those DLLs.  Thanks, Hans - I very much appreciate the help!!