# VS 2010 VB.NET ocx load failure

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm a long-time Delphi developer that's been assigned a VB.NET app built for WinXP 32-bit, to make work on Win7+ and 64-bit platforms.  I haven't used Basic since the CP/M days and haven't used any MS development environment in almost as long, but have taken the DevU intro VB courses, so I have some grasp of VB syntactically but I'm mostly lost on the vagaries of how VS puts a project together into an app.  I'm using VS 2010 (run as admin) on a Win7 64-bit system, with the project set to target x86 platform.

The app uses a couple of in-house-developed ActiveX controls, one to interface external industrial hardware via mfgr-supplied drivers, and the other to manage config settings in the registry used by those drivers.  Both these OCXes are registered successfully via Regsvr32.

I can see the IDE building the 4 interop DLLs to work with these 2 OCXes.  The app builds successfully in the IDE and starts when run, but the main form comes up blank - none of the menu items, toolbar, etc. display.  And the main form won't load in the designer - it doesn't give an error message, just loads the designer source rather than the visual designer form.  This behavior is the same whether built for debug or release.

By trying commenting out parts of the designer code, I've isolated the failure to the lines in the InitializeComponent() method that instantiate the OCX objects:

```
Me.AxDiamondctrl1 = New AxDIAMONDCTRLLib.AxDiamondctrl()
Me.AxDiamondsetupctrl1 = New AxDIAMONDSETUPCTRLLib.AxDiamondsetupctrl()
```

When the app runs, references to these two object fields fail as null reference exceptions.  I assume that because these calls are failing early in InitializeComponent(), the rest of the visual components on the form aren't being set up properly, leading to the blank main form, but since I can't step through that designer code I can't say that for sure.

To confirm that the OCXes themselves are registered and loading properly, I wrote a small test app in Delphi that loads and calls several methods/properties in them - that test program works as expected.  So I'm assuming that there's some flaw in either how those IDE-generated interop DLLs are built or in the IDE/app finding/loading them.  But I have NO idea of what might be causing that or how to address it.  I'm also curious as to why the interop DLLs (2 of them per OCX) are generated - no such extra helpers are needed by Delphi, it just builds the appropriate code from the type library.

Thanks!

Steve

Comment: How is this different than [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684671/vb-2010-assembly-doesnt-load-at-startup)?

Comment: I seem to remember that a few AX_Something controls did not play nice with the the embedded interop assemlies that became default in VS2010.  Open the References node in the solution explorer (you will need to "Show All Files") and select the AX_ Something Dlls.  Then right-click and select properties.  Set "Embed Interop Types" to False.  Make sure "Copy Local" is set to True.

Comment: Plutonix - I was trying to add more definition to maybe get closer to an answer.  Sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: TnTinMan - Embed Interop Types = False, Copy Local = True on all 4 already, and Isolated = False, but I tried changing these individually and rebuilding, with no success.